# Codemirror's Onload Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to get an instance of Codemirror using AngularJS's tabs.

`<p ng-bind-html="tab.content | unsafe"></p>` is where I insert the textArea:

```
<tabset class="tab-container">
    <tab id = "tabContent" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active"> 
      <script>

      </script>
      <tab-heading>
      <span>{{tab.title}}</span>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="removeTab($event, $index)"></i> <!-- the tab close button -->
    </tab-heading>
    <p ng-bind-html="tab.content | unsafe"></p>
  </tab>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addTab()"></button>
</tabset>
```

When I add tab.Content in, I first add HTML tags around the text in order to insert a textarea:

```
var formatText = function(text){
        return "<textarea ui-codemirror='cmOption' ng-model='cmModel'>" + text + "</textarea>";

    }
```

the ui-codemirror = 'cmOption' triggers this:

```
$scope.cmOption = {
    lineNumbers: true,
    indentWithTabs: true,
    onLoad : function(_cm){
        console.log("loaded");
        $scope.modeChanged = function(){
            console.log("loaded");

            _cm.setOption("mode", $scope.mode.toLowerCase());
        };
    }
};
```

When I add a breakpoint at $scope.cmOption, it succeeds. But when I add a breakpoint at the onLoad function, it's never reached.

Thank you for reading this long post, and trying to help :(

Comment: CodeMirror doesn't have an `onLoad` option, and will thus completely ignore your function (CodeMirror version 0.x had such a function, but anything past that loads synchronously, and thus doesn't need it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` will not compile the `ui-codemirror` directive from your string.
To do that you could use `$sce.trustAsHtml()`, but even then you won't be able to bind to `cmOption` on your scope.

I think your best bet would be to add the textarea directly into your view.
and add the text into your scope's model.

```
<p>
    <textarea ui-codemirror='cmOption' ng-model='tab.cmModel'></textarea>
</p>
```

It's not completely clear what your trying to do.  If you post the code where you call `formatText(text)` perhaps I can improve my answer.

**EDIT:**

I've tweeked my answer a little.  I think you need the cmModel/text property to be part of your tab object, so each tab gets its own value.  I would still like to see where you are using `formatText` though.

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically add new tabs which contain a textarea - so I can't directly add the textarea into the view. Is there really no way I can make the ui-codemirror/cmoption work?

Comment: I see, you are using the ngRepeat so that when a new tab is select you want to create the tab and textarea.  Let me think.

Comment: var addTab = function (text) {
  console.log(formatText(text));
  $scope.tabs.push({ title: 'Tab ' + counter, content: formatText(text)});
  counter++;
  $scope.tabs[$scope.tabs.length - 1].active = true;
 };

Comment: I know it's ugly, but that's my addTab function. In short, I add a tab to my $scope.tabs array (this is where i use my formatText), increment the tabCounter, then set the newest tab to be active.

Comment: Could you also explain why the ui-codemirror won't work with ng-bind-html/$sce.trustAsHtml? That's the part that confuses me the most I think.